# jQuery - using addClass, targeting that class, and then removing it in 2 clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my jQuery:

```
$("#nav-button").click(function() {
$("#hamburger-menu").slideToggle("slow");
$('#nav-button').css('background','url(assets/close.png)');
                            });
```

now this code lets you click on #nav-burger to open up the #hamburger-menu by making it visible (by default it's hidden with CSS). The slideToggle is a toggle, so if you click on it again it slides back up(goes back to display:none in css after a fancy animation).

You'll also notice the `"$('#nav-burger').css('background','url(assets/close.png)');"` line, which changes the background image on the #nav-burger element to close.png.

I want to make it so that the "slideToggle" only works one way; what I mean is that I like the animation for it sliding down but I would rather it abruptly disappear when the #nav-button is clicked rather than slide up in an animation.

I would also like the

```
$('#nav-button').css('background','url(assets/close.png)');
                                });
```

to return to it's previous image when clicked.

So here's what I tried:

```
$(".opennav").click(function() {
$("#hamburger-menu").css('display','none');
$('#nav-burger').css('background','url(assets/hamburger-menu.svg)');
$( "#nav-burger" ).removeClass( "opennav" );
                                });
```

Thinking that adding the class "opennav" to the navigation button would then let me select it in jQuery, but this part of the code doesn't work at all.

I'm not sure why - can jQuery not select elements that itself has used the 'addClass' function on?

This is for a class that I'm still learning but I have been stuck on this for nearly 5 hours..

[Here's a jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLffy6dc/) that kind of shows what I mean; notice that the 'X' never changes back to the menu icon, ideally that's not the case. You'll also see my poor attempt at fixing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

https://jsfiddle.net/tLffy6dc/1/

**JS:**

```
$("#nav-burger").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("opennav")) {
    $("#hamburger-menu").css('display','none');
    $('#nav-burger').css('background','url(http://connor.la/sandbox/havefunkid/hamburger-menu.svg)');
    $( "#nav-burger" ).removeClass( "opennav" );
  }
  else {
    $("#hamburger-menu").slideToggle("slow");
    $('#nav-burger').css('background','url(http://connor.la/sandbox/havefunkid/close.png)');
    $( "#nav-burger" ).addClass( "opennav" );
  }
});
```

Comment: You have no idea how much frustration you've just alleviated.... I will remember this buddy. I would have never thought to use a if else statement in this way